# ASP.NET Core Directory.EnumerateDirectories not working when deployed to Azure AppService

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I am currently experimenting with ASP.NET Core MVC by creating a simple blog with static views. I've created a custom class that implements the IViewLocationExpander in order to enumerate a directory structure to retrieve razor views

```
public class FolderEnumerationViewExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context,
        IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        var locations = viewLocations.ToList();

        foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories("Views/Blog", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            locations.Add($"/{directory.Replace("\\","/")}" + "/{0}.cshtml");
        }

        return locations.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

I've configured this class to be used within Startup.cs's ConfigureServices method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IPostsMetaDataRepositry>(new JsonPostsMetaDataRepository(ConfigurationPath.Combine("posts.json")));
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o => { o.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new FolderEnumerationViewExpander()); });
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

This seems to work perfectly when I run my application locally using IISExpress however, when I deploy the application to an Azure AppService, only a handful of the directories within ~/Views/Blog are being enumerated when trying to locate views.

I'm fairly certain the issue is one of configuration but I am having a difficult time tracking down what it could be. Any ideas as to why this may be occurring?

I have the full source of this project on GitHub for reference: https://github.com/pstricker/Develothink

Comment: Are you sure that though missing folders are getting deployed? If not, then your code is irrelevant here, and it's a deployment issue. Check what's there using Kudu Console.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Thanks for pointing me towards Kudu Console! Very helpful tool. As you suspected, not all of the folders are getting deployed, however I can't tell exactly why some folders are getting deployed and others are not.

Comment: Each file within the missing folders are configured as Content with <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>

Comment: `Not all folders are getting deployed` probably because in Asp.net Core 2.0 views are precompiled by default, so you won't see a views folder. Its done so by the setting     `<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>` in your csproj folder.

Comment: @MuqeetKhan Thanks for your comment. The views were being precompiled so their directories were not actually being deployed. This now begs the question "Is there a better way to enumerate Razor views in my application so I just take advantage of precompilation?"

Comment: @pstricker did you try changing the compilation directive to false, redeploy and see if that works?

Comment: @MuqeetKhan I did and yes, it did work. Thank you for your help. Sincerely appreciate it.